# How to customize facebook share dialogue in Qualtrics

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, qualtrics

I'm making a survey on Qualtrics and would like to distribute it via facebook. Is there a way to add open graph tags (meta tags) to my qualtrics survey so the shared post includes a image? I see that qualtrics automatically saves the survey title and description as meta tags, but I do not know how to either a) remove the blank image preview that is automatically generated when sharing the link or b) add a meta tag to display an image. Thanks for any advice!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work, but you could try putting the meta tags in the survey header under Look&Feel/Advanced.

Comment: Thanks -- I have tried that and it does not seem to work. I spoke with someone at Qualtrics yesterday who said it might be possible to use javascript to inject the tags into the head, but I don't know enough javascript to be able to figure that out.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid not having them in the html head would keep it from working. I don't think using JavaScript is going to work because it depends on a client browser to run.  I'm pretty sure Facebook is using a server instead of a browser to grab the meta tags.  While the JS is easy enough, it would be a waste of time.